# How to automate creation of Network Turn Features from line segments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing, network-analyst

I have a road network which I will add Turn features in. From the road network, I have created a model that cuts out the line segments where the turn features will be located. My problem is how to make a turn features of these line segments and get them to connect to the road network. I know how to draw in new Turn features, but there are too many turn features to draw here. There are approximately 28000 Turn features which should be included. Does anyone have a model, Python script or a solution on how to do this?

Comment: Your Question has gone nearly 6 months without anyone offering a Comment or Answer.  Consequently, I recommend that you edit it to provide more details and most likely a diagram or two to explain more precisely what you are asking.